# How to implement a constantly active loop to check for changes (boolean)?

Tags: java

I created an boolean b. I want to constantly check if b changes. If so, then an action e should be done

Comment: Don't do that. Hide your boolean b as a private variable of some class, and make it so it can only be modified by a call to a setter method. Have that method call a listener every time it changes the value of b. Basic observer pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an external Thread:

```
volatile boolean b = true;
new Thread(() -> {
  while (true) {
    boolean lastB = b;
    while (b == lastB) {
      //If you want a delay between each check:
      try {
        Thread.sleep(/*delay in ms*/);
      } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {} 
    }
    //Do something if b changes
  }
}).start();
```